# Showing Dialog in nested MaterialApp - flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm using a nested MaterialApp such that, `FirstMaterialApp` has `SecondMaterialApp` as its child. I'm facing an issue when calling `showDialog` from `SecondMaterialApp`, that is it appears on the entire screen as if it is opened from the `FirstMaterialApp`.

I want that the dialog remains confined to the boundaries of the `SecondMaterialApp`.

In the image, I have intentionally stretched the Dialog across the width so that it is apparent that it covers the `FirstMaterialApp`.

[image]

**First MaterialApp**

```
class FirstMaterialApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstMaterialApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'First Material App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('First App Scaffold'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: DeviceFrame(
              device: Devices.ios.iPhone12, screen: const SecondMaterialApp()),
        ));
  }
}
```

**Second MateriaApp**

```
class SecondMaterialApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondMaterialApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
        title: 'Second Materia App', home: SecondScaffold());
  }
}

class SecondScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondScaffold({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Second App Home'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            child: const Text('Open Dialog'),
            onPressed: () async {
              await showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (buildContext) => CustomDialog());
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomDialog({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: const [
              Text(
                'Dialog',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              Text(
                'Message Text',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution by using a `showDialog` parameter named `useRootNavigator`. Setting it to `false` provided the required results.

Now the dialog is confined to the boundaries of child MaterialApp and the `backgroundOverly` from `showDialog` covers only the second material app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

-> use  Your Second File code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class SecondMaterialApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const SecondMaterialApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return const MaterialApp(
            title: 'Second Materia App', home: SecondScaffold());
      }
    }
    
    class SecondScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
      const SecondScaffold({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Second App Home'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: TextButton(
                child: const Text('Open Dialog'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (buildContext) => const CustomDialog());
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class CustomDialog extends StatelessWidget {
      const CustomDialog({
        Key? key,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return CupertinoAlertDialog(
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: const \[
              Text(
                'Dialog',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              Text(
                'Message Text',
              ),
            \],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Now the dialog is confined to the boundaries of the second app but the background overlay still covers the first app.

Comment: send SS  Your code

Comment: didn't get it, please elaborate!

Answer (score 0):

create material before dialog

```
return Material(child: Dialogue());
```

Comment: Using Material as the parent of Dialog shows an only dialog and the parent widgets are all gone.

Comment: can you please explain what actually you want?because i run your code........

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my problem is solved and I have answered the question.
I wanted that the dialog is shown within the boundaries of the child Material app and its background overlay only covers the child Material App.